# Defining a set by induction under ZFC

Tags: set-theory

The definition of a set by induction is used in first order logic to define a couple of sets and plenty other sets can be defined in this way, for example the set of all powers of 2.

Let $X$ be the smallest set such that

- $0 \in X$,
- if $x \in X$ then $2x \in X$.

This of course does not prove anything about the existence of the set $X$ and the only possible way I can see to assert the existence is to add an axiom that says so. But this feels unpleasant because is not ZFC anymore.

In general all the definitions i saw (logic and structure van dalen) match the following criteria

Let $X$ be the smallest set such that

- $x_0, x_1, \ldots \in X$
- If $A_0, A_1, \ldots, A_{k_1} \in X$ and $\phi_1(p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_{l_1})$ then $op_1(A_0, A_1, \ldots, A_{k_1}, p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_{l_1}) \in X$
- If $A_0, A_1, \ldots, A_{k_2} \in X$ and $\phi_2(p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_{l_2})$ then $op_2(A_0, A_1, \ldots, A_{k_2}, p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_{l_2}) \in X$
- $\vdots$
- If $A_0, A_1, \ldots, A_{k_m} \in X$ and $\phi_m(p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_{l_m})$ then $op_m(A_0, A_1, \ldots, A_{k_m}, p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_{l_1}) \in X$

where $op_i$ is not a function but a notation, like $n^+ := n \cup \{n\}$ used in the axiom of infinity, $\phi_i$ is a sentence and $k_i$, $i$ or any number is not a member of $\omega$ but the concept of number used informally like the one from the pairing axiom "for any two sets there exists ...".

In van dalen for example each one of these sets has a induction principle theorem and a primitive recursion theorem with a generalized proof, similar to what we have in $w$, in fact $w$ follows this criteria.

Is there a way to get around this under ZFC (in general) or am I missing something very simple?

EDIT

Another example

Let $[Int]$ be the smallest set such that

- $nil \in [Int]$
- For every $n \in \omega$ if some $x \in [Int]$ then $n :: x \in [Int]$

(Haskell like lists of integers)

```
[1, 2, 3] = 1 :: (2 :: (3 :: nil))
```

Comment: It seems to me that you are talking about an operation $x\mapsto 2x$ on some numerical set $\Bbb U$ (which one? $\Bbb N$? $\Bbb Z$? $\Bbb C$?), and if so you can easily define your set $X$ as $$X=\bigcap\left\{V\in\mathcal P(\Bbb U)\,:\, 0\in V\land \forall x\in V,\, 2x\in V\right\}$$

Comment: This, as far as ZFC goes. I don't know about first-order logic, but I'm quite certain that this is not a first-order definition in the language of the operations on $\Bbb U$. But that's more of an $\Bbb U$-problem.

Comment: Assuming, as in the first comment, that $X$ is a subset of some number system such as $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, you can easily prove the existence of a unique such set $X$: $$X = \{0\}$$

Comment: I don't understand your other example: what does "$::$" mean? And what is "$nil$," is that just $\emptyset$?

Comment: @Noah $\mathsf{nil}$ is the empty sequence, and $::$ is an operator appending an element to the head of the given list, so $a::l$ is $\langle a\rangle^\frown l$.  I think the OP mentions them because the OP is familiar with functional programming languages.

Answer (score 3):

*(I'm going to work with $1$ in place of $0$ here, since otherwise things are a bit trivial.)*

---

There are various ways to approach this in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (or similar).

I personally like a "from-above" definition - such definitions are extremely powerful, and - while less concrete - once understood are very easy to work with. First, recognizing that we're living in the context of the natural numbers, we introduce the operation $$f: \mathcal{P}(\omega)\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(\omega): A\mapsto A\cup \{1\}\cup\{2n: n\in A\}.$$ This $f$ can be produced by separation (+ powerset/infinity of course). Now say that a set $U\subseteq\omega$ is an $f$-fixed point if it satisfies $f(U)=U$. We can then consider the **least fixed point of $f$**, namely the set $$X=\bigcap_{f(U)=U}U=\{n: \forall U\subseteq\omega(f(U)=U\implies n\in U)\}.$$ Again, this exists via separation (and we can show that it satisfies $f(X)=X$ easily). This is exactly the set we want.